# How to get textfield value from panels container in ext js

Tags: extjs

This is one Panel and initially its items will be empty.

```
var resultArray = [];
this.mainContainer = new Ext.Panel({
                border : true,
                layout : 'column',
                border : 1,
                collapsible : true,             
                title : 'Flaged Questions',
                items : [resultArray]
            });
return this.mainContainer;
```

and later in this container i am adding the items in the form of container. Container consist of textfields. and Now on button click i want to get the values of textfields.

```
this.CenterContainer = new Ext.Container({
                    layout : 'floating-form',
                    flex : 1,
                    border : true,
                    bodyStyle : 'background:#F2F2F2;',
                    style : 'padding-top:7px',
                    items : [ {
                            xtype : 'textfield',
                            labelWidth : 45,
                            fieldLabel : "<span style='padding-left:2px'>" + 'Notes' + "</span>",
                            name : 'Notes',
                            readOnly : true,
                            border : 1,
                            width : 340,
                            height : 35
                        }]
                });
this.mainContainer.items.add(this.CenterContainer);
```

Comment: Your question isn't very clear, Where is this code, where is the button? you could give the textfield an itemId and use ComponentQuery to reference it in the buttons handler. If you can supply more information/code to show the issue properly we can make better suggestions

Answer (score 0):

If you give that textfield an itemId then you should be able to get a reference to it like this:

```
var field = this.mainContainer.down('#MyTextFieldItemId');
```

See the docs on ComponentQuery if you want to get back more than just one textfield by itemId

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.0-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.ComponentQuery